# Indecomposable rings with nontrivial idempotents

Tags: ring-theory

I am looking for examples of indecomposable rings with nontrivial idempotents.  The only examples I can think of are matrix rings.  Are there other examples?

Comment: http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/Idempotent2.html

Comment: @FrankMurphy Would you mind to work out your comment?

Comment: Just that a non-trivial descomposition of a ring correspond to a set of non.trivial idempotents elements, so if you have a non-trivial idempotent you´ll have a descomposition of a your ring.

Comment: definition of indecomposable ring?

Answer (score 4):

A ring $R$ is **indecomposable** if $R$ cannot be written as $R\cong R_1\times R_2$ with non-zero $R_1$ or $R_2$. Another equivalent formulation of that is that the only *central* idempotents are $0$ and $1$, see e.g. [the article mentioned by Frank Murphy in the comments](http://planetmath.org/Idempotent).

So for giving an example, you just need a ring with non-central idempotents. As you noted the matrix ring $M_n(k)$ constitutes an example. Another example in the same vain is the ring $U_n(k)$ of upper triangular matrices.

---

As my basic examples of rings are finite dimensional $k$-algebras $A$ ($k$ a field), let me give you two remarks for this class of rings (not in full generality):

- If the field is algebraically closed, you can associate the quiver of $A$. Then $A$ is indecomposable iff the quiver of $A$ is connected. In this case, any connected quiver where there is more than one vertex gives an example: the path algebra of the quiver with idempotents being the length zero paths.
- The idempotents correspond to projective modules. Hence for an indecomposable ring, having non-trivial idempotents is equivalent to having non-free projective modules.